# How can I convert a seaborn color palette into a cmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn, colormap

I would like to convert the *continuous* diverging color palette "RdBu_r" (or really, any pre-defined color palette) in seaborn into a matplotlib colormap.

This is the closest I've come, but it creates a discrete color map, whereas I would like a continuous map:

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

palette = sns.color_palette("RdBu_r", n=7) # could make n = 100 as a quick fix
cmap = ListedColormap(colors=palette)
cmap.set_bad(color='black', alpha=0.5)
sns.heatmap(cmap=cmap)
```

Ultimately, I am trying to create a seaborn heatmap with the "RdBu_r" color palette, with null values filled in as dark squares, which is why I am trying to create a cmap with set_bad(color='black'), as opposed to just passing in "RdBu_r" into the cmap argument of sns.heatmap.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"RdBu_r"` is a matplotlib colormap. There hence seems little reason to convert it to a list of colors first. Instead just *use* it as it is.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

cmap = plt.get_cmap("RdBu_r")
cmap.set_bad(color='black', alpha=0.5)

sns.heatmap(data, cmap=cmap)
```

Comment: I was unaware seaborn uses matplotlib color maps, but that makes sense. Very helpful, thanks.